# Nested associated data through Sequelize join tables

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js

Using `Sequelize`, I'm trying to get an output like this:

```
[{
  "Id": 1,
  "Name": "Game 1",
  "Teams": [{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Team 1",
    "Users": [{
      "Id": 1,
      "UserName": "User 1"
    }]
  }]
}, {
  "Id": 2,
  "Name": "Game 2",
  "Teams": [{
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Team 1",
    "Users": [{
      "Id": 2,
      "UserName": "User 2"
    }]
  }]
}]
```

Note that Team 1 has 2 different users, but that's only because they're set up that way per game... so a user isn't tied directly to a team, but rather through a team game constraint.  Basically, my Game HasMany Teams, and my Game/Team HasMany Users... a many-to-many-to-many relationship.  I was trying to follow [this thread](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/6671), but it seems like what they're doing there doesn't actually work, as I tried doing this:

```js
// models/Game.js
module.exports = (sequelize, types) => {
  const GameModel = sequelize.define('Game', {
    Id: {
      type: types.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    Name: {
      type: types.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  });

  GameModel.associate = (models) => {
    GameModel.belongsToMany(models.Team, {
      as: 'Teams',
      foreignKey: 'GameId',
      through: models.GameTeam
    });
  };

  return GameModel;
};

// models/Team.js
module.exports = (sequelize, types) => {
  const TeamModel = sequelize.define('Team', {
    Id: {
      type: types.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    Name: {
      type: types.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  });

  TeamModel.associate = (models) => {
    TeamModel.belongsToMany(models.Game, {
      as: 'Games',
      foreignKey: 'TeamId',
      through: models.GameTeam
    });
  };

  return TeamModel;
};

// models/User.js
module.exports = (sequelize, types) => {
  const UserModel = sequelize.define('User', {
    Id: {
      type: types.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    UserName: {
      type: types.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  });

  return UserModel;
};

// models/GameTeam.js
module.exports = (sequelize, types) => {
  const GameTeamModel = sequelize.define('GameTeam', {
    Id: {
      type: types.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    }
  });

  GameTeamModel.associate = (models) => {
    GameTeamModel.belongsToMany(models.User, {
      as: 'Users',
      through: 'GameTeamUser'
    });
  };

  return GameTeamModel;
};
```

The above models create the tables just fine, with what appears to be the appropriate columns.  I then do some inserts and try to use a findAll on the Game model like this:

```js
GameModel.findAll({
  include: [{
    association: GameModel.associations.Teams,
    include: [{
      association: GameTeamModel.associations.Users,
      through: {
        attributes: []
      }
    }],
    through: {
      attributes: []
    }
  }]
});
```

The query starts to go wrong at the 2nd include with the association of the Users.  Because I'm trying to nest the users inside of the teams, I figured the join would attempt to use the unique ID on the through table (GameTeams.Id), but instead, the query ends up using this:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `GameTeamUser` AS `Teams->Users->GameTeamUser` ON `Teams`.`Id` = `Teams->Users->GameTeamUser`.`GameTeamId`
```

I figured the ON would be `GameTeams.Id = Teams->Users->GameTeamuser.GameTeamId`, but I don't know why it's not, and how to adjust it... I've tried using a custom `on` in my include (per [the docs](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll)), but it seems to be ignored completely.  Anyone have any advice?  Or possibly a better way of structuring this, so it works the way I want it to?

Comment: I've opened a [thread](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11796) on the Sequelize github

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating this thinking you have a many to many to many..and i can see that the fields for your model for GameTeam do not match up with the foreign keys you have declared in your other models...

What do your database tables look like?

Am i correct in saying, that a game has many teams, and a team has many users... however a user can only be on one team at a time, and a team is only in one game at a time? (i am assuming the game/team join and the team/user join are simply temporary records in the join tables disappearing after the game is over etc)

Comment: No, a game has many teams, and a team has many games.  A user then can be on many teams through many different games, but not always on that same team for all games, and vice versa.  The tables look like they should... Hard to put down in a comment, so I recommend looking at my other comment for the Sequelize thread.

Comment: Interesting.... i had a hard time following it through on this thread, but the other was indeed better... i am now thinking i have also run into this, i cannot recall how i got around it now but i surely did, i'll be interested to see what the solution posted in sequelize thread was... i haven't used a ton of raw queries but i have used some and that was probably my solution